# Compact bibliography with url links

Tags: bibtex, natbib, url, urlbst

I am trying to make my bibliography style similar to this one:

[image]

With very compact referencing and hyperlinks to papers. I can't find a way to do this which is this compact. I am using natbib with .bst files. Anyone have any suggestions or recognise the style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recognise the style as such, but physics reference lists (and the journal references here suggest this is an example of one such) do generally use [n]-style citations, and omit article titles, and thus end up this compact.  Therefore you might find something useful at either [this collection of physics .bst styles](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/phy-bstyles), or by looking at physics journals' BibTeX instructions.

There's a [collection of .bst samples](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) which shows some possibilities, but it doesn't include anything quite matching this.

Failing that, you might investigate the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package (it might already be installed in your distribution), which helps you generate a custom `.bst` file.

Comment: Making a custom bib works